# SQL Error 1205 Deadlock only from one machine

Tags: sql, mariadb, deadlock

In our development enviroment, I'm sometimes getting the 1205 error in Heidi when I'm trying to update or modify data. The database is on a central server that the team uses for the development enviroment.

Having read into the issue, every time I end up with the same "Using inserts or updates at the same time on one table". This is not the case for me. I'm the only user accessing this table acording to the processlist, yet only my machine returns deadlock errors. When asking someone else to execute even the most basic update query that 1205-s for me, they have no problem at all while I cannot execute it successfully.

To add to the weirdness of this issue, when a collegue modifies the same table, my following queries on that table execute without any issues. So if I execute a query, then the table deadlocks. A collegue executes the exact same query, no problem on their side. I execute a new query on the table to update/insert or such, and my queries don't deadlock anymore.

Short list of system specifications:

- Windows 10 x64
- 4GB DDR2 RAM
- Realtk PCIe GBE Family Controller (network card)
- Heidi SQL for database editing
- PHPStorm 2016.3.2 (also fails updating the database)

Does anyone know if there might be a way a certain network card or setting can cause this issues to happen?

Comment: Which MariaDB version and which engine? How fast does the timeout occur? If it's InnoDB, try to run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, it might show what other transactions it thinks are there. Run `SET GLOBAL log_warnings=3` and check the error log after the error happens. Keep in mind that if you are not a superuser, you will only see your own connections in the processlist, not all of them.

Comment: This would be MariaDB 10.0.20, and in the case of this table InnoDB. Next time the error occurs, I'll run the status command.
We all use the same user account for the database, so all commands should be running as the same user, unless it only shows queries fired from the current IP/system that's running the `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command.

Comment: Let's see the SQL and the text of the error message.

Comment: Aparently none of us can actually execute that command due to the limitations of the useraccount we use. Although I have verified it has to be something in my OS/system that casues this isse. Even hooking up my phone with tethered WiFi gives the same issue. A full reboot of the computer does temporarily fix this.
If there's settings or hardware inside the system that can cause this issue, I'd love to hear about it. I'm afraid I can't get the InnoDB status...